# Integrating grapesjs-plugin-s3 for Amazon S3 in GrapesJS/React package

Tags: reactjs, grapesjs

I am working on integrating Amazon S3 for asset storage in a GrapesJS/React package. I have included the grapesjs-plugin-s3 plugin in my project to enable S3 integration. How can we integrate Amazon S3 for asset storage in our GrapesJS/React package?

```
            <GjsEditor
              className="gjs-custom-editor text-white"
              grapesjs="https://unpkg.com/grapesjs"
              grapesjsCss="https://unpkg.com/grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css"
              options={gjsOptions}
              plugins={[
                {
                  id: "gjs-blocks-basic",
                  src: "https://unpkg.com/grapesjs-blocks-basic",
                },
                {
                  id: "grapesjs-plugin-s3",
                  src: "path/to/grapesjs-plugin-s3.min.js",
                  options: {
                    id: "grapesjs-plugin-s3",
                    name: "grapesjs-plugin-s3",
                    imgFormats: ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif"],
                    bucketName: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                    prefix: "XXXX/",
                    accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXX",
                    secretAccessKey:
                      "XXXXXXXXX",
                  },
                },
              ]}
              onEditor={onEditor}
            >

              <ModalProvider>
              </ModalProvider>
              <AssetsProvider>
              </AssetsProvider>
            </GjsEditor>
```

we need file uploader with the one from Filestack.